# Bad class file when calling in another java file

Tags: java, .class-file

When declaring a java file in another java file I get the following error.

[image: Bad Class File]

The java file which is causing the error has the following code in

```
public class NumberSettingsFile
{
    int maxSortBoxes = 50;

    public int getMaxSortBoxes()
    {
        return maxSortBoxes;
    }
}
```

And I am declaring it using the following code

```
NumberSettingsFile uniSet = new NumberSettingsFile();
```

Would someone please be able to explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A public class has to be in a file by the same name.

Comment: @Thevenin It is isn't it?

Comment: @Dan Can you show the import statements?

Comment: @manouti Do I need to import it if the two java files are in the same directory?

Comment: You said you're declaring a Java file (you mean class?) in another Java file so it sounds like you're trying to declare two classes in one file.

Comment: If they're in the same directory you do not have to import.

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Thevenin Okay. I shall add some

Comment: I think the problem may be paths.  Can you share the full command used that generates the error message displayed?

Comment: It may be a package issue - paths to files, within the classpath, are expected to be named based on the name of the package.

Comment: @ash I was just sorting out some extra code and found it was a problem with packages. I forgot to declare it went in a package in the code. Thank you for the help

Comment: Sure thing - I see that error message is confusing.  "Put X in a file named X" which is exactly what you did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by not declaring the package in which the java file was in. The code should have read

```
package GUIMain;

public class NumberSettingsFile
{
    int maxSortBoxes = 50;

    public int getMaxSortBoxes()
    {
        return maxSortBoxes;
    }
}
```